# Check for key in dict returning false even though the key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've this function:

```py
def step_list_kafka_topics(context):
    topics = context.kafka.list_kafka_topics()
    if 'my-topic-1' in topics:
        print('TRUE: {}'.format(topics))
    else:
        print('FALSE {}'.format(topics))
```

This is the response I get:

```
FALSE {b'my-topic-1': None, b'my-topic-2': None, b'my-topic-3': None}
```

I also tried `if 'my-topic-1' in topics.keys()` but got the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The keys are `bytes`, not `str`.

Comment: because your keys are bytes not strings

Comment: Strings and `bytes` (byte sequences) are seen as different by Python 3.x

Comment: `'my-topic-1'` (<class 'str'>) is not inside the `topics` dictionary. `b'my-topic-1'` (<class 'bytes'>) is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, this happens because your keys are `bytes` not `str`. So, one way to fix that is to decode them back to string like the following:

```
def step_list_kafka_topics(context):
    topics = context.kafka.list_kafka_topics()
    topics = {key.decode("utf-8") for key in topics}  #<-- just add this
    if 'my-topic-1' in topics:
        print('TRUE: {}'.format(topics))
    else:
        print('FALSE {}'.format(topics))
print()
```

Comment: As we don't actually know what OP is actually doing with this, an even easier fix will be `if b'my-topic-1' in topics:`...

Comment: As a matter of fact... yes, it's way easier :)

Comment: I would just add that the `'utf-8'` parameter is implicit. Doing `key.decode()` would be enough.

Comment: @revliscano, yes. since the default encoding is `utf-8`

Comment: Yup. Cool answer anyway. @Anwarvic +1